# KDE theme manager in pure OpenBox WM?

Tags: kde, openbox, gtk, theme

I've setup a pure OpenBox system with no specific desktop environment like Gnome, KDE, or Xfce, etc... It works well, and I have been able to customise the desktop's appearance with software like ObConf (for OpenBox themes) and LXAppearance (for GTK themes). However, I have recently installed DigiKam which is a KDE application, and its GUI does not follow what I've setup for OpenBox and GTK.

Question: How can I customise the theme in Digikam (and other KDE apps that I might use) in my system? Is there a standalone equivalent to ObConf and LXAppearance for KDE? Or is there another way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KDE apps are written using Qt, so you need to use a Qt configuration tool (package [qt4-qtconfig](http://packages.debian.org/sid/qt4-qtconfig) in Debian/Ubuntu)

Comment: qtconfig will create a config for your QT applications, which KDE is built on.  however There are specific configuration options, that are not for QT, but used by kde applications.  So qtconfig, will do the major part of a kde application look and feel.  But some parts must be specified in .kde.  The Arch Openbox wiki has more information about what settings cannot be done in qtconfig.

Answer (score 1):

I am guesing that you want "Uniform Look for Qt and GTK Applications";

- First there are counterpart or ported themes that you could use.(ported from qt to gtk which means an effort has been made to make gtk theme that looks something like a Qt theme.) `oxygen-gtk` is one of them written by Qt developers for the purpose of visual consistency between GTK+ 2.x/3.x and Qt-based applications.
- QtCurve; which is a set of widgets GTK+ 2.x, Qt4, Qt5 and KDE4. it can change varity of option like appearance of a button or shape of the sliders.

for mor information consult with [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uniform_Look_for_QT_and_GTK_Applications)